# jar файл не видит файл с конфигурациями config.properties, как решить?

Tags: java, properties

Коллеги, помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. в IDE собрал проект, полностью рабочий. через maven - package собираю jar с зависимостями. запускаю и мне прилетает ошибка

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\config.properties (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

вот где использую данные

```
public JPanel getMainPanel() {
    lableError = new JLabel();
    lableError.setVisible(false);

    FileInputStream fis;
    Properties property = new Properties();

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
        property.load(fis);
        urlPR = property.getProperty("urlPR");
        urlGZ = property.getProperty("urlGZ");
        urlRNF = property.getProperty("urlRNF");
        urlSBIC = property.getProperty("urlSBIC");
        urlPIS = property.getProperty("urlPIS");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        lableError.setText("ОШИБКА: Файл свойств properties отсутствует!");
        lableError.setVisible(true);
        System.err.println("ОШИБКА: Файл свойств properties отсутствует!\n" + e + "\n------------------");
    }


    return mainPanel;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>UFO-SOAP</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20230618</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>bytebuffer</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

структура [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я понимаю, что проблема простая. но где она?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скомпилированный исполняемый код находится в папке `target`. Откройте данную папку, найдите свой класс, в котором выполняется код, и найдите файл `config.properties`. Вероятнее всего, вы указываете путь, смотря на исходники, а надо смотреть на структуру скомпилированного проекта.

Вообще загружать таким образом ресурсы не очень корректно. Всё, что находится в пакете `resources` должно попасть в classpath. Это означает, что вы можете получить доступ к файлу более простым способом, описанном по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464366/14614707).

```java
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло